# On the position of multiple sub and superindices

Tags: positioning, subscripts, superscripts

In tensorial analysis, the position of covariant and contravariant indices may be relevant. The following image shows the output of `{A_i}^j` and `{\tilde{A}_i}^j`:

[image: Index positions]

But I expect the second expression (with the tilde) to have the index `j` at the right of the index `i`. **Why do they behave different? How can I obtain something like the first expression?**

Also, I am trying to write an expression like `{{{A_i}^j}_k}^m` (see following figure), but I get the error `Double subscript`. **How can I write something like this?**

[image: awful non-latex expression]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To separate indices, insert some blank content between them. Or, use the [`tensor` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/tensor):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tensor}

\begin{document}

${A_i}^j$ and ${\tilde{A}_i}\mathstrut^j$.

$T_i\mathstrut^k\mathstrut_\ell\mathstrut^m$

\noindent\hrulefill

$A\indices{_i^j}$ and $\tilde{A}\indices{_i^j}$.

$T\indices{_i^k_\ell^m}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! first time I see the `tensor` package. This defines another similar command `\tensor[^i_j]{T}{_k^m}` which places indices before the tensor (may be useful somehow), and `\nuclide[14][6]{C}` for chemical notations.

Comment: Just to expand, I was playing with `\mathstrut` and `{}`. I see no differences if I use `T_i\mathstrut^k` or `T_i{}^k`.