# How to change the highness of index in tensor package?

Tags: positioning, indexing, tensor

I'm having a problem with the index position in the `\tensor` command. When I write, for example, `\tensor{A}{_\ mu}`, I get a tensor with the subscript "mu" in a very low position. Is there any way I can change this? I want to raise its position a little.

Here is an example:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tensor}
 \begin{document}

    \begin{align}
          \left( \tensor{A}{_\nu} \right) \left( \tensor{A}{_\mu} \right)
    \end{align}

 \end{document}
```

The problem is that the last pair of parentheses gets bigger because of the positioning of the subscript `\mu`:

[image: Example Image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Can you put your MWE or your LaTeX code so we can help you? Thanks. This link is help for you? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339041/on-the-position-of-multiple-sub-and-superindices

Comment: BTW, what @Sebastiano was referring to as an “MWE”: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. We cannot offer much help just with a picture, or some code fragments.

Comment: Thank you for providing a compilable example! Please check my updated answer. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edited**: Your question actually consists of two different aspects.

---

### Why you should stick with the lowered subscripts with tensors

When there are no superscripts, e.g., `$A_\mu$`, the subscripts will be in a position you may find “not too low”. However, if there *are* superscripts present, e.g., `$A_\mu^\nu$`, then the subscripts will be lowered to give room to the superscripts.

Please note that the `\indices` and `\tensor` commands from the [`tensor`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tensor) package *intentionally* put the subscripts in a lowered position. So when you type something like

```
$\tensor{A}{_\mu} \, \tensor{M}{^a_b^c_d}$
```

The subscripts `\mu`, `b` and `d` will be sitting on the *same* baseline, as they should be for these two tensor objects.

If all you want is the “not lowered” version, then just type

```
$A_\mu$
```

But this, to me, destroys the meaning that `A` is a tensor, and IMHO leads to bad alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tensor}
\linespread{1.5}\selectfont% for better visual
\begin{document}
The good: $\tensor{A}{_\mu} \, \tensor{M}{^a_b^c_d}$

The bad: $A_\mu \, \tensor{M}{^a_b^c_d}$
\end{document}
```

[image: tensors]

---

### Why you shouldn’t abuse the `\left` and `\right` pair

Please don’t think that always using `\left` and `\right` is good. In fact, it is quite the *opposite*.

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2647/164314) by @rgrig quoted from the TeXBook, in which Donald Knuth, the inventor of TeX, explains why manual sizing delimiters are provided.

[This other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123545/164314) showcases examples where `\left...\right` is too small and when it is too big.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tensor}
\linespread{1.5}\selectfont% for better visual
\begin{document}
The good: $\bigl[ (\tensor{A}{_\nu}) - (\tensor{A}{_\mu}) \bigl]$

The bad: $\left[ \left(\tensor{A}{_\nu}\right) - \left(\tensor{A}{_\mu}\right) \right]$
\end{document}
```

[image: tensors with delimiters]

Comment: Upvote your answer and for your comment on my name for the question :-).